# If graphSAGE can be converted to solve the regression problem?

Tags: pytorch, regression, gnn, graphsage

I have tried to solve the node classification problems by graphSAGE and it works well on dataset Cora. Now I want to convert it to solve the regression problem, and I only change the loss function into `torch.nn.MSE()` without any change to other parts of the code.

However, the loss does not decrease. So I'm wondering if graphSAGE can be used to solve regression problem and how should I convert it?

ps:

My code is from this website:https://github.com/ytchx1999/GraphSAGE-Cora-Citeseer-Pubmed/tree/main
And I only change the dataset and convert `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(DEVICE)` to `criterion = nn.MSE().to(DEVICE)`.